# Run function only once (display toast like message) javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function inside a for loop that displays a message. Now to my question, is it possible to display that message only once? I have heard of the .one() function in jquery but don't know if its achievable in this case.

```
for(var in variable){
   $('.confirmToast').html("Can't filter your selection").fadeIn(400).delay(3000).fadeOut(400);//Can this be run only once?
}
```

Comment: Why are you executing the code multiple times if you want it to execute once? Just dont put it in a loop...?

Comment: Its complicated. Its code with over 1000 lines and its hard to explain it all, but thats the way it is, I'm just asking if its possible or not. =)

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need it to be in a loop, and can't change the conditions for the looping, I would put the message in an if statement. Start off making a variable false, put the message in an if statement that runs if the variable is false, and make the variable true so it doesn't run at the next loop. I'll try a hand at it below.

```
messageOnce = false;

for(var in variable){
if (messageOnce = false) {
$('.confirmToast').html("Can't filter your selection").fadeIn(400).delay(3000).fadeOut(400);//Can this be run only once?
messageOnce = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could change the **for** loop to use the **$.each** function in jquery to break out from the loop by just returning false.

e.g.

```
var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
        $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
            $('.confirmToast').html("Can't filter your selection").fadeIn(400).delay(3000).fadeOut(400);
            return false;
        });
```

Hope this helps :)